# Multiple layer map with legend

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, geom

I am trying to get a map from 2 different layers.
The first one represent country borders, the second one are grid-cells over the same area.

Drawing the map itself isn't much of an issue :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data=country, color = "black", fill = "white", size=1)+
  geom_sf(data=grid, color = "black", fill = NA)
```

The code allow to get a map with the country borders with a thick black line and a white background. Then the grid layer is added with a thinner black line and a transparent color background to avoid hidding the country borders from the first layer.

I would like a 2-entry legend called "Legend", the first entry being the thick black lined/white background "Country border" and the second entry being the thinner black lines for "Grid border".

After trying for a few hours, I cannot get something that get close to this. I understand I need to tell R to link objets to their representation using AES statement, but each time I tried the whole map was changed (no borders, only grid-cell borders etc).

I'm not used to work wwith map in R so I don't really know how to provide a MWE in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have the data your working with, so here is an example. All you need to do is put some term in `aes` that is not already used for defining features (e.g., size, shape, color, fill, alpha, etc.). Usually you do not quote anything in `aes`, but we do here just to put it in the legend. If you want to mess with the aesthetics of the legend, you can then further edit using `guides`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)


usa <- map_data("usa") |>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)|>
  group_by(group)|>
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) |>
  st_cast("POLYGON")

AL <- map_data("state") |>
  filter(region == "alabama")|>
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"),
           crs = 4326)|>
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) |>
  st_cast("POLYGON")

ggplot()+
  geom_sf(data=usa, color = "black", fill = "white", size=1, aes(shape = "Country border"))+
  geom_sf(data=AL, color = "black", fill = NA, aes(alpha = "Grid border"))+
  labs(shape = "", alpha = "")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !
is there a way to display ''Legend'' or something lese on top of the actual legend please ?

Comment: yes, you could add `shape = "Legend` in `labs`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different example using a country and a grid:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = country, aes(fill = "Country border"), size = 1)+
  geom_sf(data = grid, fill = NA, aes(color = "Grid border"), size = 0.25) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "white", guide = "legend", name = "Legend") +
  scale_color_manual(values = "black", guide = "legend", name = NULL) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(0, "mm"),
        legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(0, 0, 15, 0)))
```

[image]

---

**Data used**

```r
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)

country <- ne_countries(10, country = "United Kingdom", returnclass = "sf")

pts <- lapply(c(-10, -5, 0), function(x) matrix(c(x, x, 48, 62.5), nrow = 2))
pts <- c(pts, lapply(2 * 24:31, function(x) matrix(c(-12, 2, x, x), nrow = 2)))
grid <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_multilinestring(pts), crs = st_crs(country)))
```